# http POSTs over a certain size failing when authentication is enabled

Tags: python, json, authentication, flask, werkzeug

I've developed a fairly simple web service using Flask (Python 2.7, current Flask and dependencies), where clients POST a hunk of JSON to the server and get a response.

This is working 100% of the time when no authentication is enabled; straight up POST to my service works great.

Adding HTTP Digest authentication to the endpoint results in the client producing a 'Broken Pipe' error after the 401 - Authentication Required response is sent back... but only if the JSON hunk is more than about 22k.

If the JSON hunk being transmitted in the POST is under ~22k, the client gets its 401 response and cheerfully replies with authentication data as expected.

I'm not sure exactly what the size cut-off is... the largest I've tested successfully with is 21766 bytes, and the smallest that's failed is 43846 bytes. You'll note that 32k is right in that range, and 32k might be a nice default size for a buffer... and this smells like a buffer size problem.

The problem has been observed using a Python client (built with the 'requests' module) and a C++ client (using one of Qt's HTTP client classes). The problem is also observed both when running the Flask app "stand-alone" (that is, via `app.run()`) and when running behind Apache via mod_wsgi. No SSL is enabled in either case.

Comment: How is the authentication enforced? Most likely the POST body is not completely read by the time you are sending the 401 response back.

Answer (score 2):

It goes as follows:

1. your client POSTs JSON data without authentication
2. server receives the request (not necessarily in one long chunk, it might come in parst)
3. server evaluates the requests and finds it is not providing credentials, so decides stopping processing the request and replies 401.

With short POST size server consumes all and does not have time to break the POST requests in the middle. With growing POST size the chances to interrupt unauthorized POST request is higher.

You client has two options:

Either start sending credentials right away.

Or try / catch broken pipe and react to it by forming proper Digest based request.

The first feeling is, something is broken, but it is rather reasonable approach - imagine, someone could post huge POST request, consume resources on your server while not being authorized to do so. The reaction of the server seems reasonable in this context.

Comment: It looks like the small POST size is a constraint in Flask's toy httpd; things were resolved by running as a proper WSGI application behind Apache's mod_wsgi.

Comment: @ChrisHerborth Good to know. Flask's httpd is notorious for being unstable.